# What is the justification for having labeling for factors in R?

Tags: r

Anyway factor is internally stored as encoded integer. Then what is the user of labeling it?

For example, say I create a simple factor:-

```
> x<-c("Manager","Engineer","Manager","Manager","Manager","Engineer","Director")
> designation<-factor(x)
> designation
[1] Manager  Engineer Manager  Manager  Manager  Engineer Director
Levels: Director Engineer Manager
> str(designation)
Factor w/ 3 levels "Director","Engineer",..: 3 2 3 3 3 2 1
```

Now, since 'designation' is a factor, internally it is being stored as integer. As far as our convenience is concerned, R is showing it already as strings to us since it knows the mapping between those strings and the integers as it must be storing that metadata somewhere. So then where does the need arise to have labeling on top of this? Why does R have to support this labeling feature for factors?

Comment: Maybe this previous answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663500/5067372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`labels` argument in `factor()` will allow you to change the name of the levels.

For example, I have a requirement that `Manager` should be `MD`, `Director` should be `Exec` and `Engineer` should be `Asst_Commiss`, then I can take the existing factor and change their names using `labels` argument.

```
x <- c("Manager","Engineer","Manager","Manager","Manager","Engineer","Director")
designation <- factor(x)
designation

new_desig <- factor( designation,
                     levels = c( 'Manager', 'Director', 'Engineer'),
                     labels = c( 'MD', 'Exec', 'Asst_Commiss') )

new_desig
# [1] MD           Asst_Commiss MD           MD           MD           Asst_Commiss
# [7] Exec        
# Levels: MD Exec Asst_Commiss
```